# How to solve a RuntimeWarning - discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a discord bot and I want to make cogs.

I typed this code:

```
for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        client.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")
```

And it returns the Error:

```
C:\Users\ivanb\OneDrive\Работен плот\ivan4o bot\main.py:37: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BotBase.load_extension' was never awaited
  client.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

As of discord.py 2, the [load_extension](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.load_extension) has become a `coroutine` (or `async function`, if you will), so you need to await it.

**Before**

```py
client.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")
```

**After**

```py
await client.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")
```

For more information, you may look at discord.py's [Migrating to v2.0](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html#extension-and-cog-loading-unloading-is-now-asynchronous).

Comment: Ok i'm awaiting it but as if you remember (i guess) awaiting works only on async functions and that's not an async function!

Comment: Of course, I know that it needs to be in a coroutine, but I did it as an example.